# matplotlib: How do I add commas to marker labels?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following dataframe:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(
[[2006, 371934],
 [2007, 403230],
 [2008, 401525],
 [2009, 421313],
 [2010, 422322],
 [2011, 412859],
 [2012, 396279],
 [2013, 393809],
 [2014, 387727],
 [2015, 339470],
 [2016, 314864],
 [2017, 286225],
 [2018, 246773],
 [2019, 214617]],
columns=['year', 'arrests']
)
```

[image]

I created the following plot using matplotlib:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df_test.year, df_test.arrests, marker='o')
ax.set_xlabel("Year")
ax.set_ylabel("Number of Arrests")
ax.set_title("Arrests by Year")
plt.xticks([x for x in df_test.year])
plt.xticks(rotation = 90)

for i,j in zip(df_test.year, df_test.arrests):
    ax.annotate(j, xy=(i,j))

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(
    ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda y, p: format(int(y), ','))
)
```

plt.show()

[image]

How do I add commas to the marker labels?

And how would I separate the marker labels so they don't overlap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same function `format` in annotate. For the separation of annotations, one easy way is to increase the size of plot:

import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

```
# increase the size here
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,9))
ax.plot(df_test.year, df_test.arrests, marker='o')
ax.set_xlabel("Year")
ax.set_ylabel("Number of Arrests")
ax.set_title("Arrests by Year")
plt.xticks([x for x in df_test.year])
plt.xticks(rotation = 90)

for i,j in zip(df_test.year, df_test.arrests):
    # format to add `,` here
    ax.annotate(format(int(j), ','), xy=(i,j))

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(
    ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda y, p: format(int(y), ','))
)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: When I saved the plot using `ax.figure.savefig()` it came out like this: https://i.imgur.com/4NB6Ic8.png Did you apply additional formatting?